# Ansible include task files based on conditional

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Just getting into `ansible` and want to know if you can include a file in a task `main.yml` based on a variable passed in `--extra-vars`?

Example;

`main.yml` -- from role/tasks

```
# Upload latest json to s3
- include: upload-code.yml
```

`playbook.yml` -- from playbooks

```
- name: Launch cloudformation stack
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  roles:
    - launch.cloudformation
```

As you can see `playbook.yml` includes a `role` and the `main.yml` includes `upload-code.yml`

How can I include `upload-code.yml` based on a conditional like below

`ansible-playbook playbook.yml --extra-vars "include=upload"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by applying a `when` condition to the include task.

```
- include: upload-code.yml
  when:
    - include is defined
    - include == "upload"
```

Or, if you have multiple include files you could also use `include` as part of the name.

```
- include: "{{ include }}-code.yml"
  when: include is defined
```

Answer (score 3):

Since version 2.4 of Ansible, the new `include_tasks` or `import_tasks` should be used, as `include` was removed in version 2.16.

`import_tasks` should be used for fixed file names:

```
- import_tasks: upload-code.yml
  when:
    - include is defined
    - include == "upload"
```

And `include_tasks` should be used to dynamically import the file at runtime depending on some logic:

```
- include_tasks: "{{ include }}-code.yml"
  when include is defined
```